# Making clickable row

Tags: javascript, php

```
<tr onclick="document.location= 'delete.php?id="<?php $row['id'];?>"'>
    <td><?php echo$row['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo$row['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo$row['phone'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo$row['address'];?></td>

</tr>
```

where is the problem ????

I need to let the row of table clickable but it does not worked ,and every row will go to diffrent website , I will send "`id`" in the URL and another web will get the "id" through GET method

Comment: 1. You are mixing quotes, only using `"document.location='delete.php?id=<?php` will suffice 2. You do not `echo` or `print` the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call javascript method and pass the `id` in it. And, inside your javascript method use `ajax`.

```
onclick="callMethod('<?php $row['id'];?>')"
```

You can write `ajax`like below

```
function callMethod(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function (html) {
            alert('Successfully Done!!');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: tell me how       plz